# Is 2 some sort of identity (like 0 and 1 are)?

Tags: notation, binary-operations

I am not a serious mathematician, and I am barely familiar with some of the topics of higher maths. From YouTube videos, I learned about the Graham's Number and Knuth's arrow notation, which is a generalization of the pattern: addition → multiplication → exponentiation ($\uparrow$) → tetration ($\uparrow\uparrow$) → pentation ($\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow$) → etc.

Independently, I've realized that:

$$2\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow2 = 2\uparrow\uparrow2 = 2\uparrow2 = 2\times2 = 2+2 = 4$$

… and it looks like the identity holds for higher orders of operation (above pentation); in fact, it is not hard to see that it holds for *all* orders, with any number of arrows.

Is it a well-known fact? Is it a particularly interesting one? Can $2$ be an identity of some kind, just like $0$ is an additive identity, and $1$ is a multiplicative identity?

Comment: What do you know of an identity?  Is $2\uparrow 3 = 3$?  Is $3\uparrow 2 = 3$?  What does that mean about $2$'s status as an identity?

Comment: Yes. This is a very good observation. That is what mathematics is: looking for patterns in abstract objects and processes. The word for this in mathematics is "fixed point". Why do you think that $2$ is a fixed point of the process of Knuth's arrow notation?

Comment: Your identity is known (but nice, indeed). See for instance the wikipedia entry [Hyperoperation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) at $H_n(2, 2)$.

Comment: @HolyKnowing Thanks, the term "fixed point" indeed sounds more appropriate